# ubuntu20.04 does not recognize my built-in webcam

Tags: drivers, 20.04, usb, intel, webcam

How do I install the webcam driver?
Also my pc responds like this.

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 27c6:55b4 Shenzhen Goodix Technology Co.,Ltd. Fingerprint Reader
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
lsusb -t
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/6p, 10000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/12p, 480M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 480M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

Comment: There does not seem to be a webcam in your `lsusb` output. The `8087:0aaa` device is a Bluetooth radio and the others are properly named. What is the brand and model of your computer?

Comment: I am using Lenovo IdeaPad S540-14IML.

Comment: Scanning through [the compatibility list on Linux-Hardware.org](http://linux-hardware.org/?view=computers&vendor=Lenovo&model=IdeaPad+S540-14IML+%28All%29), it looks like `lsusb` should see your camera. Is there a hardware switch that you need to slide over to enable the camera on your notebook?

Comment: There is no such thing as a hardware switch.

Comment: Let's check if the webcam is recognized by Windows 10.

Comment: sorry. It was a hardware issue, not an Ubuntu issue. When I started it with Windos10, the webcam was not recognized. Immediately, when I checked the USB connection, it was recognized. thank you very much!